# Average of values according to the criteria in a column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need to take an average of each symbol for each subject.  Sample data is shown in the screenshot.  I tried using this formula, but it is showing an "DIV" error;

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(A2:A49 ="<>",C2:C49))
```

[image]

Comment: You are using `FILTER` in the wrong order. It is the range you are filtering, then the condition. Along that you will be unable to average the value as you do not indicate which column to average.

Comment: You have the filter arguments mixed. First range, then the arguments array: `=AVERAGE(FILTER(C2:C49,A2:A49 ="<>"))` and judging by the picture: `=AVERAGE(FILTER(C2:C49,(A2:A49 ="<>")*(B2:B49=$F2))`

Comment: Also requested to post using **[Mardown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)** so it helps members of the forum to copy the sample data!

Comment: have you tried using the pivot table....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can spill the whole output using <kbd>MAKEARRAY()</kbd> (I'm bit late because I was copying the data using Excel Camera tool, hence which needed some fixes).

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(F2:F5),COLUMNS(G1:L1),LAMBDA(α,φ, 
  AVERAGE(FILTER(C2:C41,(A2:A41=INDEX(G1:L1,φ))*(B2:B41=INDEX(F2:F5,α))))))
```

---

Please ensure to change cell references and ranges accordingly as per your suit.

---

BTW, for `Beta Users` one can spill the whole data using <kbd>PIVOTBY()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F7</kbd>

```
=PIVOTBY(B2:B41,A2:A41,C2:C41,AVERAGE,,0,,0)
```

---

Comment: Thanks @Mayukh Bhattacharya  array worked for me.  Pivotby, is it an extension?  I tried this but it didn't worked.

Comment: Its a new function launched in `Beta` Channel of Excel, you can read **[here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pivotby-function-de86516a-90ad-4ced-8522-3a25fac389cf#:~:text=The%20PIVOTBY%20function%20allows%20you%20to%20group%2C%20aggregate%2C,PIVOTBY%20%28row_fields%2Ccol_fields%2Cvalues%2Cfunction%2C%20%5Bfield_headers%5D%2C%20%5Brow_total_depth%5D%2C%20%5Brow_sort_order%5D%2C%20%5Bcol_total_depth%5D%2C%20%5Bcol_sort_order%5D%2C%20%5Bfilter_array%5D%29)**

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing the `FILTER` syntax. It is range followed by conditions.

Take a look at this:

`=AVERAGE(FILTER($C$2:$C,$A$2:$A=G$1,$B$2:$B=$F2))`

Drag this formula across the range to autofill other values.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you just need a [`Pivot Table`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

1. Select a cell inside your data
2. Go to Insert ribbon
3. Add Pivot Table
4. Select Subject to rows
5. Select Symbols to columns
6. Select Time A to Values and the right click and change sum to average

sample data and result

[image: 2]